# Prevent access to php files (folder) with .htaccess EXCEPT for XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, security

I have a folder `www.mysite.com/page/panel/soascripts/` where there are 10 different PHP files.
I want to prevent access to the folder **soascripts** and the php files in it. Except `X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest` (for ajax). Is this possible with htaccess?

Comment: Why bother? Are people likely to stumble across it and be confused? Adding an `X-Requested-With` header is trivial if any attacker wants to do something nefarious with the data.

Comment: Well, I just want it. In my logs I already saw some accesses. I don't want it as a single security option, I already implemented an authorization secr. (I know that an attacker can easily manipulate the header) but I want this for regular users. They should not stumble in this directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your soascripts folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,F]
```

So without the

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

request header, the response will be a 403 forbidden.

---

EDIT:

If you want to add the rules to the document root, you just need to include the path:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
RewriteRule ^page/panel/soascripts/[^/.]+\.php$ - [L,F]
```

Make sure to add it *before* any type of routing rules (like stuff being sent to `index.php`).

Comment: [It's sub-optimal practise to have *any* .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when).

Comment: JonLin Thank you. @Quentin I don't have a lot of directories or files. I just want to prevent anyone from display-raping the php files and I don't know how else to archive this. hm, I've read the article.... will this also slow down my php mysql queries to my database in the **soascripts** folder?