# htaccess: deny pages from all except XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xmlhttprequest

I have on my host a pages that i want to prevent access to theme except through XMLHttpRequest, so i have already tried this code on htaccess file but it doesn't work:
in this code the target page is: "localhost/page/table.php"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
```

in the rewriteRule i don't know what to write.
i have already trying to search in [Prevent access to php files (folder) with .htaccess EXCEPT for XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097071/prevent-access-to-php-files-folder-with-htaccess-except-for-xmlhttprequest) but that doesn't help enough.

EDIT

i have tried this code, the page table.php are not accessable but there is no XMLHttpRequest response:

javascript code :

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("contentp").innerHTML =
  xhttp.responseText;
    }
 }   
 xhttp.open("GET", "table.php?doc=" + str1 + "&module=" + str2 , true);
 xhttp.send();
```

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
RewriteRule table-view+.php$ - [L,F]
```