# access php file only from index.php?p=test

Tags: javascript, php

im using winwheel.js + custom.js , i have also test.php where file is called by Custom.js to get random StopPosition, all works fine, my question is how can i restrict accessing file test.php?action=try directly, because if i access that file it calls php functions (**payWheel()**,**getReward()**)

**test.php** generate an item that will be won if someone will spin the wheel

**Custom.js**:

```
function startSpin() {
    if (wheelSpinning == false)
    {
        var jsonData = null;
        $.getJSON("wheel-responder.php?action=rotate", function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            WheelOfFortune.rotationAngle = 0;
            WheelOfFortune.animation.spins = 10;
            WheelOfFortune.animation.stopAngle = data["lastPosition"];
            WheelOfFortune.startAnimation();
            wheelSpinning = true;
        });
    } }
```

**test.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['action']))
    {
            if($mycredit>= 100){ 
                if($_GET['action'] == 'try')
                _Spin(rand(1, 10), 100);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Use htaccess to block access to NON XHR requests (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097071/prevent-access-to-php-files-folder-with-htaccess-except-for-xmlhttprequest) Then use **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to only allow access to that file from your domain. The theory here is that the first will stop non ajax requests, and the second will stop ajax calls from other domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict the casual user make it a POST request. That would prevent random access thru address bar.

JS FILE

```
$.post("wheel-responder.php?action=rotate", function (data) {}
```

PHP FILE

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {}
```

Not tested but should be trivial.

Comment: and how can use `$.getJSON` function in same time ?

Comment: I think only difference is you need to `var obj = JSON.parse(data)` yourself instead of `getJSON` doing it for you.